# Cómo hacer responsive un mapa de Google Maps

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo puedo hacer responsivo al incorporar el mapa de google maps?

Por ejemplo, esta es la línea de etiquetado que te genera google para insertarlo en tu html:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d13566.89508901391!2d35.2354079!3d31.7780191!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xe33f01a44e2808aa!2sDome+of+the+Rock!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2smx!4v1477799410016" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

En la hoja de CSS, ¿cómo lo puedo hacerlo responsive?

Comment: Hola @Soter. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías mencionar si intentaste algo y agregar ese código a la pregunta (por más que no funcione?

Comment: Gracias @Mariano , lo que intentaba hacer era poner al final, mas o menos por el foorter, poner un mapa de la dirección de dicha empresa, pero cuando insertaba el codigo que generaba google, no quedaba responsive, era mas que nada por mi hoja de estilo, lo que hice fue como el ejemplo de este Dev. Joel y me sirvió.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mediante `css` sería

```
iframe {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Otra opción sería añadir el `iframe` dentro de un `div` y empleando [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)  asignar la clase `row`

```
<div class="row">
<iframe src="..." width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Dev.Joelme sirvió tu ejemplo, e hice unas modificaciones para que se ajustara como si fuera mi foorter

Answer (score 2):

Yo suelo usar 100% de ancho y un alto fijo en lugar de automático. Por ejemplo:

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Si el alto fijo no es suficiente para ti, puedes hacer que varía con CSS condicional según el alto de pantalla.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @jpussacq

Comment: Cuando gustes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No uses `<iframe>`, ponlo en un div y quitale las propiedades `width` y `height`.

Añádele una clase, y ya con eso usando media queries lo haces responsive como cualquier otro elemento.

Comment: Hola @Diego Fuentes. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por aportar! ¿Podrías explicar cómo esto solucionaría la pregunta realizada, mostrando con un breve fragmento de código cómo se implementaría? Por otro lado, el contenido del mapa se está cargando automáticamente en un iframe. ¿Cómo se cargaría usando un div?